# Why does my shellcode segfault when executed from C, but not as a stand-alone executable?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, shellcode

I'm trying to execute a shell with shellcode. I've made this code in a 64-bits machine:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    xor rax, rax
    push rax
    mov rbx, "/bin//sh"
    push rbx
    mov rdi, rsp
    mov al, 59
    syscall

    mov al, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

After using nasm and linking with ld if i execute the file this works fine. The problem is if i get the shellcode from this and tried to execute it with this program:

```
int main(){
    char *shellcode = "\x48\x31\xc0\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x48\x89\xe7\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05\xb0\x3c\x48\x31\xff\x0f\x05";

    (*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
}
```

It gives me a segmentation fault error. I can't see what's wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Already tried the `gcc -z execstack` to make the stack executable, still gives a segmentation fault error

Comment: Already tried the "gcc -z execstack" to make the stack executable, still gives a segmentation fault error

Comment: The registers rsi and rdx have garbage in your C program. And the syscall execve needs these registers.

Comment: @sinkmanu Thanks!! That was the problem. If someone lift this "marked as duplicate" thing and if you make an answer i will accept it.

Comment: Your wellcome. @jester tagged the answer as duplicate, but it is not the correct duplicate answer...  So, now nobody can answer you until you unlock the duplicate hehe (anyway, that was the answer to your problem)

Comment: Reopened. Also note that the exit syscall is wrong - it can only be reached if the exec fails in which case `rax` will definitely not be zero and so only setting `al` to `60` is not enough hence that will also fail and ultimately cause your segfault.

Comment: `strace` and / or `gdb` would have shown you the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal, because your shellcode is not setting the registers rsi and rdx, and when your C program executes the shellcode will have garbage in the registers rdi and rdx. It is because the syscall **execve** needs more arguments.

```
int execve (const char *filename, const char *argv [], const char *envp[]);
```

As extra information, the segmentation fault is because after your execve syscall you will get an error in rax and you will move 60 to the last 8 bits of rax and call to this syscall that doesn't exist.